Unable create multiple private DNS record with same name pointing to the private IP of Azure API Management via terraform
Below is my code for creating multiple DNS a record. I can see only the record gets created for DNS zone scm.azure-api.net and not for other DNS zones. Kindly suggest how can i achieve this?
    resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "apiprivatednszone" {
      for_each = var.pvtdnsrecord
      name                = var.always_same_name ? "azdlgleuw-apim-apimngname-001" : each.value.zone
      zone_name           = each.value.zone
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
      ttl                 = 300
      records             = ["10.0.1.4"]
    }
    
    
 
Below is my variable file
    
    variable "always_same_name" {
      default = true
    }
    
    
    variable "pvtdnsrecord" {
      type = map(any)
      default = {
        azurerecord = {
          name = "apim-test-001",
          zone = "azure-api.net"
        },
        portal = {
          name = "apim-test-001",
          zone = "portal.azure-api.net"
        },
        developer = {
          name = "apim-test-001",
          zone = "developer.azure-api.net"
        },
        mngmnt = {
          name = "apim-test-001",
          zone = "management.azure-api.net"
        },
        scm = {
          name = "apim-test-001",
          zone = "scm.azure-api.net"
        }
       
      }
    }

